# Trigger Sagemaker pipeline on Github code push

Tags: github, single-sign-on, webhooks, amazon-sagemaker

We have a Github organizations account which uses SSO-based auth using PingID IDP. We would like to trigger the AWS Sagemaker pipeline on code push to the GitHub repo. We are looking for a webhook kind of way to achieve this integration. Please suggest easy ways to achieve this setup. Let me know what else info I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

To kick of a SageMaker Pipeline there is a `StartPipelineExecution` API call that you can use: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_StartPipelineExecution.html

Comment: Thanks for your response but that is not what we are looking for. We need to trigger the pipeline along with the code, which should be passed to the pipeline as well.

Comment: What code? The code running in one of the Pipeline steps? Say a Training Job?

Comment: Yes, that code needs to pass on to the Sagemaker pipeline for training job

Comment: You can use Pipeline Parameters to parameterise the s3 location of your script that runs in the job https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-parameters.html

Comment: Looks like that's the option we may have to try but we needed a seamless approach just like codepipeline in sagemaker pipelines